# How do I load my NetBeans project into sonarqube?

Tags: java, netbeans, sonarqube, netbeans-8, sonarqube5.1

I got an embarassing question. We just started programming a new project with Java in NetBeans. In School we once loaded it to sonarqube, but if I try http://localhost:9000/ (after starting sonarqube) in explorer there is only the old version of the project on my dashboard. I forgot the way to upload the current version of my project to sonarqube.

Thank you for your help

Comment: That is embarrassing?

Answer (score 4):

You need to run an analysis. Assuming yours is a Maven project, open a command prompt, and:

```
cd my/project/dir
mvn clean install
mvn sonar:sonar
```

Note that the two Maven commands could be combined: `mvn clean install sonar:sonar`

Comment: Uff, first of all, thank you for the help. It did something but now I have the problem that the new project in sonarqube is empty. It ran an analysis. The old version got deleted and a new one got created BUT it shows 0 LOC and 0 technical debt...Any ideas?

Comment: I can only guess that your sources aren't in the normal place. Try setting a `<sonar.sources/>` property in your pom

Comment: To be honest, I don't know exactly where to put it in the pom